# C4211: Nonstandard extension used : redefined extern to static

Tags: c++, warnings

I'm currently eliminating some compiler warnings from my source code. I have a function with the following function signature for which I get the C4211 warning.

```
static void setBits(const std::vector<bool>& flags, std::vector<Results::Bits>& bits, int index, int errors)
```

The warning says

```
C4211: Nonstandard extension used : redefined extern to static
```

What is the cause for this warning? I'm using the VC2003 compiler.
To be honest, I could not find the reason with my Internet research and the MSDN documentation. I have similar functions in other projects and there I don't get the warning at all.

Comment: I don't use Microsoft's compiler, but according to the error message, I'd assume that `setBits` was originally declared as `extern void setBits(...)` (most likely in a header file) and later in the definition it has been defined as `static void setBits(...)` instead.

Comment: Since `extern` is the default, the following minimal example causes this warning on a modern MSVC: `void f(); static void f();`

Comment: Could you formulate an answer to close this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I was getting a similar error during linting.

Seems like you have defined the function as **static**.
However, its declaration says it is an **extern**. (Extern is by default).

Try to grep/search your function name in your source code and fix the declaration.

For more info check this [link.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/error-messages/compiler-warnings/compiler-warning-level-4-c4211?view=vs-2019)